# image_picker/image_picker.dart Library crashes when gets permission of camera

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();

 void openResource(String permissionType) async {

 if(permissionType == ImageSource.camera){
  final XFile? pickedImage = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

}}


//Method called
openResource(ImageSource.camera);
```

App gets crashed after getting permission of camera successfully. I had given camera permission in android manifest file. Please let me know how can I resolve this crash

Comment: can you share the version of the package?

Comment: If your app crashes you did not catch an exception that was thrown. Look in the logcat which one.

Comment: My current version of image_picker: ^1.0.5, I have added a try catch block then also emulator shuts down. Could you please help ?

Comment: In logcat I get ===>
Lost connection to device.
adb: device offline
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.